# Как спроектировать структуру небольшой БД?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
В которий раз сел разбираться с структурой БД "students". Все началось с непонятно откуда взятого задания без входных данных для БД (препод сказал, что легко самому понять что и как делать). Первое, что меня смутило какую структуру выбрать для следующих пунктов:

- найти среднее значение оценок по каждому студенту;
- найти максимальную оценку по каждой дисциплине;
- найти среднюю оценку, выставленную каждым преподавателeм;
- вывести минимальную оценку, выставленную каждым преподавателем;
- перевести каждую оценку в рейтинговый бал (оценка, большая 3 баллов,
  увеличивается в 2 раза);
- подсчитать количество разных групп;
- подсчитать количество различных квартир;
- вывести среднюю оценку, максимальную оценку, минимальную оценку для
  студента с кодом 3;
- подсчитать количество  хороших оценок;
- подсчитать процент двоек, выставленных каждым преподавателем;
- вывести количество оценок, для которых выполняется условие;
  «оценка*2+1>10».

Стало интерестно с самого начала: о входных данных догадывайся сам + задания, судя по всему, переводились в переводчике ("количество квартир").

Решил создавать БД следующей структуры:

1. Точно будут 5 таблиц: "students", "groups","teachers","disciplines","marks";
2. Связи "студент - группа" - "многие к одному"; "препод - оценка" - "один к многим"; "студент - дисциплина" - "многие к многим"; таблица "marks" связывает студентов и дисциплины, преподов и дисциплины (препод может вести несколько дисциплин, а одну дисциплину могут преподавать несколько преподов), один и тот же препод может вести в нескольких студентов (студентов разных групп);

Здесь начинается самое интерестное. С MySQL имею дело недолго (1 лаба по оператору "SELECT"). Там в БД было две таблици ибо связь один ко многим - все понятно. Во первых, как правильно выбирать сущности для связей,то - есть знаю, что логично связной таблицей выбрать "marks", "groups" со "students" ,  "students" привязать к "discipline", но ведь, в принципе связь можно  создавать и между сущностями "teachers" и "disciplines напрямую как "дисциплины" с "группами" да и вообще. 
Еще интерисует вопрос связанный как мне связать имеющуюся структуру к аудитории, вернее к имеющейся структуре "присобачить" аудиторию (квартиру) ), ведь если создать таблицу "auditorium" и связывать аудиторыю с оценкой, например, в таблице "marks" будет много лишних связей, а это не надо.

Дайте, пожалуйста, ответ на вопрос с корректным выбором сущностей, и о том какую таблицу следует ввести и с какими полями ее создавать, с какой связывать.
Поймите меня я не лентяй и не тупица, хотя не мне об этом судить. Препод ведущий лабы год сам только после учебы работает, вообщем понимаете сами, что приходится самому разбираться, а когда задание неполноценное, о чем вообще тогда идет речь.
Ниже привожу пока что наработанную структуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Удалять и перезадавать вопрос -- плохая идея.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3946/181100)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы решал такую (малую, обозримую, без требования дальнейшего расширения) задачу от обратного - написать каждый запрос по заданию, и на основе них уже сформировать сущности и связи необходимые и достаточные для выполнения запросов.

> найти среднее значение оценок по каждому студенту

`SELECT studentid, studentname, AVG(markvalue) avgmark  FROM students JOIN marks ON students.studentid = marks.markid`

> найти максимальную оценку по каждой дисциплине;

`SELECT subjectid, subjectname, MAX(markvalue) maxmark FROM subjects JOIN marks ON subjects.subjectid= marks.subjectid`

> найти среднюю оценку, выставленную каждым преподавателeм

`SELECT teacherid, teachername, AVG(markvalue) avgmark FROM teachers JOIN marks ON teachers.teacherid= marks.teacherid`

подведём итог на этих трёх запросах. Нам нужны таблицы students и teachers с полями для имён и первичного суррогатного ключа. Нужна таблица subjects с полями для названия дисциплины и первичного суррогатного ключа. Ещё нужна таблица marks с полями для внешних ключей на таблицы students и teachers и subjects, для значения оценки, для первичного суррогатного ключа.

Ну и так далее...

Comment: спасибо за совет, буду пробовать

Comment: столкнулся с новым вопросом, допустим каждый предмет может вестись в разных аудиториях (например, в разные дни или даже в один и тот же), есть список аудиторий и дисциплин. Мы их связываем через таблицу "занятие" (lesson) по id аудиторий и предметов. При том каждое занятие имеет свою дату. А в таблице "mark" есть дата оценки. Согласитесь выходит какой - то бред так как "оценки" связаны с "предметом", которые в свою очередь связаны через занятие с аудиториями. И выходит, что мы ищем аудиторию в которой была выставлена оценка по дате из "lessons"???????

Comment: Вы сказали создавать таблици по заданию,но ведь там не указано какие именно выбрать разные аудитории: разные из тех, в которых были выставлены (так логично, ведь если просто брать из списка групп они все будут уникальными) или инные оценки, или разные вообще????

Comment: Пожалуйста ответьте очень хочу разобраться

Comment: Достаточно просто привязать оценку к аудитории через внешний ключ, допустим таблици "auditorium" (id.auditorium), ведь так???? Но тут возникает новый вопрос, не много ли связей в таблице "marks", мне говорили, что очень много связей в одной таблице чревато последствиями. Как бы Вы поступили в данной ситуации, как следует поступить мне?

Comment: 1) я говорил "написать каждый запрос по заданию" 2)"на основе них уже сформировать сущности и связи **необходимые и достаточные** для выполнения запросов" 3)про аудитории в вашем вопросе одно задание, которое вообще не требует внешней связи для этой сущности 4) "очень много связей в одной таблице" вам шашечки или ехать? 5)комментарии не предназначены для расширенных дискуссий

Comment: понял, спасибо.